# Updating several model data at one ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2

It's possible, to update or get data by post request from something like this?

```
$jobs = Jobs::find()->select(['name'])->all();

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['document/generator?id='],
    'id' => 'doc_form',
]);?>

<?php for($i=0; $i<count($jobs);$i++):?>

<?= $form->field($jobs[$i], 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?php endfor;?>

<div class="form-group text-right">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Jo\'natish', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

Why I'm asking about that?

HTML name, id attributes have the same, similar values.

[image]

Comment: Take a look here : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-forms#activefield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Collecting tabular input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-tabular-input) like follows:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();

foreach ($settings as $index => $setting) {
   echo $form->field($setting, "[$index]value")->label($setting->name);
}
ActiveForm::end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a proper id assing proper values in  options array

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#field()-detail

```
    <?= $form->field($jobs[$i], 'name', [
        'id'=> 'job-name-'.$i,
    ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```